# Pyinstaller including font but python not finding it

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wanted to use a font in my pygame game and it worked just fine in vscode(using custom class):

```
menuCaption = objects.Text(display,"ROCK PAPER SCISSORS", 100, "minecraftiaregular.ttf", antialiasing = False)
```

The thing is, when I built the app using Pyinstaller onefile, it didn't detect the font. I have included the font in the .spec file so I have no idea what might have caused this.
Spec file:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['pkn.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('objects.py','.'),('minecraftiaregular.ttf','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='pkn',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

When I run the app, this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Moje\tomek nowy\programowanie\python\zajecia programistyczne\pliki\papier kamien\pkn.py", line 29, in <module>
    menuCaption = objects.Text(display,"ROCK PAPER SCISSORS", 100, "minecraftiaregular.ttf", antialiasing = False)
  File "objects.py", line 15, in __init__
    font = pygame.font.Font(self.fontface,self.fontsize)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'minecraftiaregular.ttf'
[20384] Failed to execute script 'pkn' due to unhandled exception!
```